# promoting diet products is haram or halal

Tags: food

I want to know that is permissible to promote diet products in Islam like keto diets and resurge. Resurge is a product that helps to lose weight. Because I want to promote that product and I will get some commission.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents is halal, you can promote it. Diet seems to become almost a religion for some people but it isn't. Muslims can make a diet, too.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether the products that you are promoting are Haram or Halal. You also have to clarify if it has halal ingredients or not.

And yes you can surely earn a commission out of it too until you don't lie or hide anything from the customers.